# Order MySQL table by two columns of equal importance

Tags: mysql

I have a two player game which stores scores in a table.

I want to select high scores from the table, this is my current code:

`SELECT * FROM games 
ORDER BY GREATEST(player1Score,player2Score) DESC 
LIMIT 10`

The problem is it only returns one instance of each row, even if for example the lower of the two scores in row 1 warrants inclusion in the top 10.

Comment: How many rows will there be in the table? Do you need to be concerned about performance? Do you have an index on `player1Score` or `player2Score`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, player1Score AS score FROM games
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, player2Score AS score FROM games
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Also, don't use `SELECT *`. List the columns explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

```
( SELECT *, player1Score as score
  FROM games 
  ORDER BY score DESC 
  LIMIT 10
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT *, player2Score AS score 
  FROM games 
  ORDER BY score DESC 
  LIMIT 10
)
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off creating a players table and a join table (even though there are only two users). Then you could easily create a query to do what you're trying to do.  Of course, it will take a little bit to alter your update/save functions to match the new schema.

```
players
-----
playerId
playerName

joinPlayerGame
-----
joinId
playerId
gameId

games
-----
modify the player score fields to just be 'score'

SELECT g.*, p.playerName FROM players p INNER JOIN joinPlayerGame j ON j.playerId = p.playerId INNER JOIN games g ON g.<whatever your key is> = j.gameId ORDER BY g.score DESC LIMIT 10
```

I hope that helps, good luck!